# Is it possible to insert a link preceding the Wolfram link at the bottom of html documents?

Tags: export

At the bottom of the html document produced by Mathematica is a link to Wolfram's site.

It says: Created by **Wolfram *Mathematica* 8.0**

I think it would be nifty to have the option to precede that link with a custom link.

For example: Copyright 2012, **Fred Daniel Kline** - foo@bar.com

*Note: I prefer my email as an image to prevent netbots from grabbing it.*

Perhaps we could have a special cell that, if present in the notebook, would be displayed automatically.  Edited: Also would like this option for pdf's.

Comment: By using Export[] to save the HTML format, you can specify your own .css stylesheet

Comment: @belisarius, I'm aware of that, thanks.  I also want this to happen for pdf file.  I edited the OP to make it clearer.

Comment: We don't really need your email, so you could've very well written `foo@example.com` ;) That way you needn't have worried about bots...

Comment: What I would do is to import the resulting HTML page as an `XMLObject` and postprocess, then export again. I did something similar for the web version of [my book](http://www.mathprogramming-intro.org/).

Comment: For PDFs you can change the PageFooter option of the notebook.  This'll put a footer text on *every page*, which may be too much.  If it is, perhaps the easiest way is to add a cell at the end by hand..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
filename = "MathematicaToHTMLExample";
nb = First[Notebooks[filename<>".nb"]];
dir = NotebookDirectory[nb]
SetDirectory[dir];
Export[filename<>".html", nb, "HTML",
"CSS"->dir<>"stylesheet.css",
"ConversionRules" -> {
    "Text" -> {"<p class='Text' style='font-size: 100%'>","</p>"},
    "DisplayFormula" -> {
"<p class=\"DisplayFormula\" style='text-align: center;"<> 
    "font-size: 200%'>","</p>"}
}]
in = ReadList[filename<>".html", "String", NullRecords -> True];

out= Join[
in[[1;;16]],
{
"<div id=\"wrap\">\n",
"<div id=\"top\"></div>\n",
"<div id=\"content\">\n",
"<div class=\"header\">\n",
"<h1> Page Header </h1> \n",
"<h2> subtitle </h2> \n",
"</div>\n",
"<div class=\"middle\">\n"},
in[[17;;-8]],
{"<p> Your custom footer </p>"},
in[[-7;;-4]],
{"\<
</div>
<div id =\"clear\"></div>
</div>
<div id =\"bottom\"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
\>"}];

strm = OpenWrite[filename <>".html"];
WriteString[strm,#<>"\n"]&/@out;
Close[strm]
```

Comment: Assume you have a notebook saved and currently open called MathematicaToHTMLExample.nb that you would like to convert to html.To convert it with a custom stylesheet and footer just run this code changing two things: 
1. Replace "stylesheet.css" with your stylesheet saved in the in the same directory as MathematicaToHTMLExample.nb
2. Replace the string "footer" with what you want.